# Очень длительная загрузка страниц, как исправить?

Tags: php

Привет всем, есть сайт написанный на php, где большинство страниц загружается в пределах 10-30мс, но также есть некоторые страницы, загрузка которых состовляет 40000мс и более. Как можно исправить такое положение вещей? Как лучше провести профилирование и понять в чем проблема?

Сервер Ubuntu 13.10 + Apache + nginx + MySQL + PHP

Answer (score 4):

Это раз [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), а это два - [xhprof](http://xhprof.io/)

Comment: еще системные ресурсы посмотреть... да и предысторию неплохо узнать...

Comment: @thunder Вы имеете ввиду комманду top?

Comment: ну например да, вдруг сайту не хватает памяти и он работает из swap?   посмотреть опять же кто кушает процессор, это может быть как апач и как и при обращении к базе. если последнее, то возможно там таблицы поврежденные либо слишком много записей для, опять же, текущей конфигурации сервера. ну и то, что предложено выше конечно.